# Undefined table error: Extending User's Plugin

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am trying to extend the user's table to add more fields to it and i have this as my code in the php file in the updates folder.

```
<?php namespace Corymillz\Store\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class AddNewFeilds extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->string('store_title')->nullable();
            $table->text('store_description')->nullable();
            $table->string('background_color')->nullable();
            $table->string('font_color')->nullable();
            $table->string('font_family')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('last_seen')->nullable();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        $table->dropDown([

            'store_title',
            'store_description',
            'background_color',
            'font_color',
            'font_family',
            'last_seen'
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I run the refresh command in console
**`php artisan plugin:refresh Corymillz.Store`** I keep getting the error

> undefined variable: table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `down()` method missing code

> It should look like this

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn([
            'store_title',
            'store_description',
            'background_color',
            'font_color',
            'font_family',
            'last_seen'
        ]);
    });
}
```

> In your code its complaining about `$table variable` as it was not defined, also instead `dropDown` you need to use `dropColumn.`

if any doubts please comment.